# Import gzipped SQL dump to H2

Tags: sql, h2, gzip

I have an SQL dump which is gzipped and I would like to import it directly into an H2 databse without having to uncompress it first. Is this possible somehow using a similar method as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/903832/how-to-import-data-to-an-in-memory-database)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just discovered `RunScript.execute`:

```
Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(
                new GZIPInputStream(
                new FileInputStream(dumpFile)));
RunScript.execute(connection, reader);
```